# Transactional database and Datawarehouse on the same Postgresql cluster?

Tags: database, database-design, cluster

Is it conceptually feasible to have on a Postgresql Cluster a transactional database and at the same time a datawarehouse that would get feeded by the transactional database ?

Comment: I think this would be more suitable on StackOverflow (please don't repost it there though, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: @Péter lol i just moved the question here because it was voted for closing on ... StackOverflow !

Comment: oops. Sometimes it is really difficult for a question to find its place. To me this sounded more like a technical (not subjective) question, but apparently there were at least 5 guys over there who saw it differently. (Nowadays there seem to be lots of people voting to close posts very fast on SO, even for strange reasons, which IMHO is not a good thing...) So let's just keep your question here then, hopefully you will get good answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is feasible. However, whether it should be done or not would depend on capacity (CPU / and IO) requirements of these two databases.